# :dependent => :delete_all not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got 2 models with a 1 to many association that I try to get a rails cascading delete working on.

I'm fairly new to rails and I've tried everything I could but I still can't get it to work...

Here are my 2 models

```
class CmsHomeSlide < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :slide_order, :start_datetime, :end_datetime, :slide_type, :header, :headline, :cta_text, :cta_link, :active
    has_many :cms_home_slide_detail, :dependent => :delete_all
    validates_presence_of :slide_type, :slide_order
end

class CmsHomeSlideDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :start_datetime, :end_datetime, :position, :image_url, :link, :cms_home_slide, :active
    belongs_to :cms_home_slide
end
```

And the test script I'm using (as a runner, but dev environment and test environment fail the same way)

```
CmsHomeSlide.delete_all
CmsHomeSlideDetail.delete_all

slide = Factory(:home_slide)
det1 = Factory(:home_slide_detail, :cms_home_slide => slide, :position => 1)
det2 = Factory(:home_slide_detail, :cms_home_slide => slide, :position => 2)

puts "Slides length #{CmsHomeSlide.all.length}"
puts "Details length #{CmsHomeSlideDetail.all.length}"

slide.delete

puts "Slides length #{CmsHomeSlide.all.length}"
puts "Details length #{CmsHomeSlideDetail.all.length}"
```

Output is

```
Slides length 1
Details length 2
Slides length 0
Details length 2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:dependent => :delete` or `:dependent => :destroy`

From the guide:

> If you set the :dependent option to :destroy, then deleting this
>   object will call the destroy method on the associated object to delete
>   that object. If you set the :dependent option to :delete, then
>   deleting this object will delete the associated object without calling
>   its destroy method.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Tried `:delete`, this is not working, it's breaking the model `::in configure_dependency_for_has_many: The :dependent option expects either :destroy, :delete_all, :nullify or :restrict (:delete) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: and destroy does not do anything, same issues

Comment: Also, you need to call `Model.destroy_all`. Using `delete_all` will not run the callbacks.

Comment: @Damp I suggest `:dependent => :destroy`. It will be the safest for you.

Comment: What do you mean by `Model.destroy_all`. At which point and on which object should I run this? I thought that :dependent would make rails run the deletion queries on the children automatically. And I have tried `:dependent => :destroy`. It does not do anything at all either, the children records are still in the db

Comment: @Damp instead of `CmsHomeSlide.delete_all and CmsHomeSlideDetail.delete_all`, do `CmsHomeSlide.destroy_all and
CmsHomeSlideDetail.destroy_all`.  This code does not go in the model, but rather wherever you are running the delete from.

Comment: ok these are for the first 2 lines of my test file, just there to empty the db... Regardless, it still doesn't solve the cascade delete not working...

Comment: Oh by you put me on the right track, doing slide.destroy instead of slide.delete did trigger the cascade... I guess it's an oddness I'll have to get used to. Thanks, I'll accept your answer since it helped me get to the bottom og it

Comment: @Damp - Yes, using `delete` will not trigger any cascades. Using `destroy` will